# PHP: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress

Well, I know the basic reason for the error message.

The problem is, I'm in over my head. I can't find an example of how to fix this that more closely matches my 'bad' code (nor did I write this script).

So here's the bad part:

```
$querystr = "SELECT M.post_id from $wpdb->postmeta M
  JOIN $wpdb->posts P
      on P.ID = M.post_id
  WHERE P.post_type = '".AttorneyProfilePosttype::$slug."'
AND M.meta_key = 'user_id'
AND M.meta_value = '".$author_id."'";

$post_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($querystr));
```

I believe I should be adding a $s, $d, or something... unsure, really... Any help would be appreciated.

-Evan

Comment: Please check the "related" sidebar on this page. There are several questions about the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this while you have directly passed the parameters in query

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT M.post_id from $wpdb->postmeta M
  JOIN $wpdb->posts P
      on P.ID = M.post_id
  WHERE P.post_type = '".AttorneyProfilePosttype::$slug."'
AND M.meta_key = 'user_id'
AND M.meta_value = '".$author_id."'";

$post_id = $wpdb->get_var($querystr);
```

or try this

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT M.post_id from $wpdb->postmeta M
      JOIN $wpdb->posts P
          on P.ID = M.post_id
      WHERE P.post_type = %s
    AND M.meta_key = 'user_id'
    AND M.meta_value =%d",AttorneyProfilePosttype::$slug,$author_id ));
```

### [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared queries is good against sql injection. And AFAIK this is the proper way to do this:

```
$querystr = "SELECT M.post_id from $wpdb->postmeta M
  JOIN $wpdb->posts P
      on P.ID = M.post_id
  WHERE P.post_type = %s
AND M.meta_key = 'user_id'
AND M.meta_value = %s";

$post_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($querystr, AttorneyProfilePosttype::$slug, $author_id));
```